# Create auto-increment field with entity framework 6.0.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, auto-increment, sharpdevelop

Good morning,

I am trying to define an autoincrement field with EF 6.0.2 (for SharpDevelop). I am using code-first approach as the modeling component for edmx files crashes in my installation.
I am targeting .NET 4.0 client profile with my solution.

This is my code-snippet for defining my field as autoincrement:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int idEmail { get; set; }
```

I get the following error message when compiling:

```
The type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' exists in both 'c:\Users\123\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\NotesConnector\packages\EntityFramework.SharpDevelop.6.0.2\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'. (CS0433)
```

That means to me DatabaseGeneratedAttribute exists in EF 6.02. as well as in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DataAnnotation in .NET 4.0. I searched http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907.aspx#apidocs for 'DatabaseGenerated' but could not find a documentation for this attribute in EF - only in ComponentModel-Namespace...

How do I solve this problem?!

Comment: Are you sure you are using .NET4.0 version of EF ? I'm pretty sure I've seen somewhere that there are 2 versions of EF ... .NET4.0 and .NET4.5. You could of course specify the full name of the data annotation (depending on which one you want)

Comment: At least so says the error message. I unzipped the nuget package and it contains both versions of EF - .NET4.0 and 4.5...

Comment: Indeed, EF 6 contains the attribute and System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations contains it also. You should try to specify the full name of the attribute : `[System.CompoenentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DataBaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` or use an alias in the using statement you've done (you can choose the one you want from EF or DataAnnotations, but I would choose the one from EF since it has prolly been reviewd for the EF6 release)